# All the labels in my laptop (ubuntu) is gone, it seems I have pressed keys that I didn't notice. How can I put the labels back

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Labels are gone, everywhere

[[image: Labels are gone, everywhere[1]]

My terminal's text are gone, only pictures show but the labels are all gone everywhere I click, even in my directories. How can I put it all back? I have pressed keys that I didn't notice, please help me.